# dont work event on script for element on partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

i have index.cshtml view with script

```
$("#SearchingManagerId2").on("change", function () {
                var valueForSearch = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("FillQualificationTable")',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    async: false,
                    data: { year: currentYear, ManagerId: valueForSearch },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#tableContainerQualification').html(data);
                    },
                });
            });
```

also i have partial Qualification on it.
its contain two actions that include 2 more partials

```
<body>
    @Html.Action("SetSearchFilterQualification")//This one return filter SearchingManagerId2
    @Html.Action("FillQualificationTable")//This one return table thats must be refresh 
</body>
```

Why my script dont working on partial (Qualification) And where i must deploy it

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is in the rendering order, if you attach the event (SetSearchFilterQualification) after the table creation (fillQualificationTable) the script doesn't find the DOM object because is not rendered yet. Try changing the order of the actions.

```
<body>
    @Html.Action("FillQualificationTable")//This one return table thats must be refresh 
    @Html.Action("SetSearchFilterQualification")//This one return filter SearchingManagerId2
</body>
```